# Complex sequence problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. Suppose $e^{it(x_n)}$ and $e^{is(x_n)}$ are both convergent for some positive numbers $t$ and $s$ with $t/s$ irrational. Does it follow that $(x_n)$ is convergent?

I know the statement this wrong when the additional condition of $t/s$ being irrational omitted. Help me with some hints. I got this problem from 
https://statmathbc.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $a_k := \operatorname{dist}(2k\pi,\mathbb N)$. Then zero is a cluster point of $(a_k)$. Let $k_n\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_{k_n}<\frac 1n$. Then there exists some $x_n\in\mathbb N$ such that $|x_n-2k_n\pi|<\frac 1n$. Hence $e^{2\pi ix_n} = 1$ trivially converges and $$
|e^{ix_n}-1| = |e^{ix_n}-e^{2k_n\pi i}|\le 2|x_n-2k_n\pi| < \frac 2n.
$$
But obviously $(x_n)$ does not converge.